# How to assert that an Uni throws a given error?

Tags: java, quarkus, mutiny

I have a reactive Quarkus project and I'm trying to test a method that returns `Uni<User>`. The method looks like this:

```java
public Uni<User> searchUser(ObjectId userId) {
        return userRepository
            .findById(userId)
            .map(user -> {
                if (user != null) {
                    return user;
                } else {
                    throw new BusinessException("Could not find an user with the given id.");
                }
            });
```

So far, so good. Now I'm trying to test a method asserting that an error is thrown when the repository returns `null` on `findById`. According to [mutiny's documentation](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/1.7.0/guides/testing/), this is how you assert that an Uni throws an error:

```java
Multi<Object> multi = Multi.createFrom().failure(() -> new IOException("Boom"));

AssertSubscriber<Object> subscriber = multi
        .subscribe().withSubscriber(AssertSubscriber.create(10));

subscriber.assertFailedWith(IOException.class, "Boom");
```

This is my adapted version:

```java
        @Test
        public void shouldThrowAnErrorWhenUserIsNotFound() {
            Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Uni.createFrom().nullItem());

            AssertSubscriber subscriber = service.searchUser(new ObjectId()).subscribe().withSubscriber(AssertSubscriber.create());

            subscriber.assertFailedWith(BusinessException.class, "Could not find an user with the given id.");
        }
```

But it doesn't build. I get this error on the

> .subscribe().withSubscriber()`call:`Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should implement 'io.smallrye.mutiny.subscription.UniSubscriber<? super br.com

How can I fix this? Or is there another way to write such a test?

Comment: Try with `AssertSubscriber<User> subscriber` . Also, you should use `awaitFailure()` before `assertFailedWith` (if the failure is emitted asynchronously).

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `AssertSubscriber` assignment fixed the type error, and now the test is working as expected.

```java
        @Test
        public void shouldThrowAnErrorWhenUserIsNotFound() {
            Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Uni.createFrom().nullItem());

            service.searchUser(new ObjectId())
                    .subscribe()
                    .withSubscriber(UniAssertSubscriber.create())
                    .assertFailedWith(BusinessException.class, "Could not find an user with the given id.");
        }
```

Comment: Now I realize the error was that I was trying to use `AssertSubscriber` rather than `UniAssertSubscriber`.